# Grid 960 menor que a tela

Tags: css, grid

Estou começando a usar o [960.gs](http://960.gs) system grid css porém estou tendo alguns problemas relacionados ao tamanho da tela, por favor me corrijam se estiver errado.

inclui todos os arquivos css corretamente dentro do header só que quando utilizo uma classe por exemplo `container_16` o tamanho não se adequá ao tamanho da tela, isso é um pouco obviu porque o grid system de 16 tem apenas 940px só que também já tentei usar o arquivo `960_24_col.css`, apos incluir este arquivo as divs filhas de `container_24`não obedecem ar larguras estipuladas por classe, todas elas aparecem com o witdh "auto" e não criam as "caixinhas"

Conseguem ver na imagem abaixo o espaço em branco que fica ao lado esquerdo? como eu poderia fazer para que preenche-se toda a tela? (a imagem esta usando o `container_16`)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo esta o html qu estou usando.

```
<div id="container" class="container_16">
        <nav class="grid_16">
            Header
        </nav>

        <section id="menu1" class="grid_16">
            <img src="assets/img/banner.png" />
        </section>

        <div class="grid_16">
            <h2>Produtos</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="prod1" class="grid_4">
            <p>
                <img src="assets/img/prod1.png" height="258" width="243">
                Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="prod2" class="grid_4">
            <p>
                <img src="assets/img/prod1.png" height="258" width="243">
                Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="prod3" class="grid_4">
            <p>
                <img src="assets/img/prod1.png" height="258" width="243">
                Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="prod4" class="grid_4">
            <p>
                <img src="assets/img/prod1.png" height="258" width="243">
                Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="arvore" class="grid_8">
            <p>
                <img src="assets/img/arvore.png" />
                Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="sustentabilidade" class="grid_8">
            <h1>Sustentabilidade</h1>
            <p>
                Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
            </p>
        </div>


        <footer class="grid_16">
            <h1>footer</h1>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para atingir sempre a largura total da tela, você precisaria adaptar este grid para porcentagem, recalculando os PX em %.

Algo do tipo:

```
.container_16 {width:100%}
.grid_1 {width:6.25%} /* 100% / 16 */
.grid_2 {width:12.5%} /* 100% / 8 */
```

Não sei se vale muito a pena... Recomendo que use o Bootstrap (ou Foundation) com a classe **.container-fluid**

Assim o seu container vai ter 100% da tela e as DIVs internas a porcentagem equivalente.